# Read ansi file and convert to UTF-8 string

Tags: php, file, ansi

Is there any way to do that with PHP?

The data to be inserted looks fine when I print it out.

But when I insert it in the database the field becomes empty.

Comment: try using mysql_real_escape_string() php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php maybe the string to be inserted contains characters that are used my MySQL

Comment: i read the string from the txt file and find that some of them return ansii some of them return empty by using mb_detect_encoding($data), any solution

Comment: There is not such a thing as `ANSII`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$tmp = iconv('YOUR CURRENT CHARSET', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

or

```
$tmp = utf8_encode($string);
```

Strange thing is you end up with an empty string in your DB. I can understand you'll end up with some garbarge in your DB but nothing at all (empty string) is strange.

I just typed this in my console:

```
iconv -l | grep -i ansi
```

It showed me:

```
ANSI_X3.4-1968
ANSI_X3.4-1986
ANSI_X3.4
ANSI_X3.110-1983
ANSI_X3.110
MS-ANSI
```

These are possible values for **YOUR CURRENT CHARSET**
As pointed out before when your input string contains chars that are allowed in UTF, you dont need to convert anything.

Change UTF-8 in UTF-8//TRANSLIT when you dont want to omit chars but replace them with a look-a-like (when they are not in the UTF-8 set)

Comment: `utf8_encode` converts from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8. So it can only be used if the input encoding is ISO 8859-1

Comment: i try $data = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $data); it out Message: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. If data was actually ASCII (which is not, as the error message states) you wouldn't need to convert.

Comment: i read the string from the txt file and find that some of them return ansii some of them return empty by using mb_detect_encoding($data), any solution

Comment: When returning false, simply open the file and look with your eyes for garbage. Remove it by hand and try again. If this works you could write a filter function to run before detecting the encoding.

Answer (score 8):

"ANSI" is not really a charset. It's a short way of saying "whatever charset is the default in the computer that creates the data". So you have a double task:

1. Find out what's the charset data is using.
2. Use an appropriate function to convert into UTF-8.

For #2, I'm normally happy with `iconv()` but `utf8_encode()` can also do the job if source data happens to use ISO-8859-1.

## Update

It looks like you don't know what charset your data is using. In some cases, you can figure it out if you know the country and language of the user (e.g., Spain/Spanish) through the default encoding used by Microsoft Windows in such territory.

Comment: I hate those editors that use the word “ANSI”. It’s similar to incorrectly using “Unicode” for UTF-16.

Comment: The OP told you about the return values he got from mb_detect_encoding.

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` doesn't really do what most people think. In fact it's close to useless. At most, you can use it to distinguish between UTF-8 and UTF-16, but you need to configure it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, using `iconv()` can return false if the conversion fails.

I am also having a somewhat similar problem, some characters from the Chinese alphabet are mistaken for `\n` if the file is encoded in UNICODE, but not if it is UFT-8.

To get back to your problem, make sure the encoding of your file is the same with the one of your database. Also using `utf-8_encode()` on an already utf-8 text can have unpleasant results. Try using  `mb_detect_encoding()` to see the encoding of the file, but unfortunately this way doesn't always work. There is no easy fix for character encoding from what i can see :(